# CakePHP 3 Table Name with underscore

Tags: cakephp

I am new to CakePHP. I am using cakephp 3.2

I have created a table stock_exchanges and controller StockExchangesController.php

My Controller Code :

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;

class StockExchangesController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash'); // Include the FlashComponent
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $stockExchanges = $this->StockExchanges->find('all');
        $this->set(compact('stockExchanges'));
    }

}
?>
```

I want to access the table **without having created the Table Class**.

the following line gives error

```
    $stockExchanges = $this->StockExchanges->find('all');
```

The Error is

Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
File D:\wamp\www\Projects\cakephp\src\Controller\StockExchangesController.php
Line: 20

**EDIT:**
@AIPD TECH in a comment below mentioned

$stockExchanges = TableRegistry::get('StockExchanges');

If the table name is posts, then i am able to access using $this->Posts->find('all'); . So is $this->StockExchanges->find('all'); not the way to access table with underscore in it ? Do I have to use TableRegistry ?

Also, Please note that I am not being able to access my controller StockExchangesController as /stock_exchanges/ , I am only being able to access as /stockexchanges/

Please help.

Bhargava

Stack Trace:

```
( ! ) Xdebug: user triggered in D:\wamp\www\Projects\cakephp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Template\Error\fatal_error.ctp on line 36
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0010157320{main}(  )..\index.php:0
20.14903911888Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(  )..\index.php:37
30.20804779240Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(  )..\Dispatcher.php:87
40.27805081520Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction(  )..\Dispatcher.php:114
50.27805081848call_user_func_array:{D:\wamp\www\Projects\cakephp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Controller\Controller.php:429}
(  )..\Controller.php:429
60.27805081984App\Controller\StockExchangesController->index(  )..\Controller.php:429
70.28405078216Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->Cake\Error\{closure}(  )..\BaseErrorHandler.php:0
80.28505079400Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->handleFatalError(  )..\BaseErrorHandler.php:98
90.32005314816Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->handleException(  )..\BaseErrorHandler.php:217
100.32005314920Cake\Error\ErrorHandler->_displayException(  )..\BaseErrorHandler.php:179
110.33305417224Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->render(  )..\ErrorHandler.php:144
120.33405421048Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer->_outputMessage(  )..\ExceptionRenderer.php:192
130.33405421296Cake\Controller\Controller->render(  )..\ExceptionRenderer.php:320
140.35505699392Cake\View\View->render(  )..\Controller.php:611
150.35705701304Cake\View\View->_render(  )..\View.php:587
160.35805702264Cake\View\View->_evaluate(  )..\View.php:952
170.35905727864include( 'D:\wamp\www\Projects\cakephp\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Template\Error\fatal_error.ctp' )..\View.php:992
180.36005745400xdebug_print_function_stack
(  )..\fatal_error.ctp:36
```

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post the _complete_ error message including the _full_ stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP!

Comment: `$this->StockExchanges = TableRegistry::get('StockExchanges');` will do that for you

Comment: thanks for your reply @aipd tech. I am new to cakephp, so i want to know, if that is "right" way" to do it ? I mean is there no other "default" way in which i can access stock excchanges ? For eg. if the table name is posts, then i am able to access using $this->Posts->find('all'); . So is $this->StockExchanges->find('all'); not the way to access table with underscore in it ?

Comment: @Bhargava By default if you are doing `$this->StockExchanges->find('all')` in `StockExchangesController.php` it should work as you are following cakephp conventions

Comment: @aipd tech thanks for that clarification :)

Comment: what is `$this->StockExchanges` - i.e. `debug($this->StockExchanges)`? Pretty sure this has nothing to do with underscores as that's completely normal. Your app code (which you need to put in the question - the controller and model files) probably contains an error; at a guess you created files by hand instead of using bake and have typos somewhere.

Comment: @AD7six, Yes I have not yet used bake, I tried to use bake but could not. I will post that separately. And Yes, Apologies it is not $this->StockExchanges, but $stockExchanges , I am about to edit my question.